# The given URL is not allowed by Client_id

Tags: azure, oauth

I have implemented Google authentication with web API 2 and getting following error:

> The given URL is not allowed by Client_id 'ngAuthApp' configuration.

This works when I change `AllowedOrigin` to `(localhost)` but not working in `api.mytouchstones-uat.net` in Client table after azure release.

My code is the following:

```
        // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);    
        //Configure Google External Login
        googleAuthOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId     = Common.Constant.GoogleClientId,
            ClientSecret = Common.Constant.GoogleClientSecret,
            Provider     = new GoogleAuthProvider()
        };
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleAuthOptions);
```

Comment: have you manged to solve / figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and this was the first google result for me. So I thought I might answer if someone else stumbles upon this question.

I guess you followed [this guide](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/), or similar.

Check that your redirect_uri that you send to Facebook/Google etc is the same as the one you have as AllowedOrigin in dbo.Clients.

And make sure that the same uri are allowed in your Facebook/Google appsettings.